# PNG transparent backgrounds appearing black when using Bitmap in LayerList of XML Shape Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout

PNG transparent backgrounds appearing black when using Bitmap in LayerList of XML Shape Android Studio. Is this bug in Android studio?

[Screenshot Output](https://pasteboard.co/JtB6BZZ.png)

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



        <item
            android:height="76dp"
            android:width="76dp"
            android:top="66dp"
            android:start="66dp"
            android:fillColor="#00000000"

            >
                <bitmap
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_power_sign"
                    android:tint="#00ffff"
                    android:fillColor="#00000000"
                    android:tintMode="screen">
                </bitmap>
        </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Try to use android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: I try that,  not work

Comment: Can you please post a picture of what you actually want the layout to look like?

Comment: Excuse me for asking unclear question. the real issue happen when i set android:tint property. in normal, BNG image is transparent. i want to change color of image. Please see screenshot link in post